# apply min max scalar to multiple dataset using loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have n data-frames. I want to apply min- max scalar to each of them.

```
from sklearn import preprocessing

x = df1.values #returns a numpy array
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
x_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(x)
#df11= pd.DataFrame(x_scaled)
x_scaled1 = pd.DataFrame(x_scaled, columns = df1.columns)
```

for one df. I tried several ways. Everything failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please list out the methods you have tried for your problem.
However, you can store the dataframe objects in a list. And then you can scale each of the dataframe as you loop through the list. I am doing it for two dataframes but the same applies for n number of these.

```
df1 = {'col1' : np.random.randint(1,26,10) , 'col2' : np.random.randint(1,26,10)}
df2 = {'col1' : np.random.randint(1,26,10) , 'col2' : np.random.randint(1,26,10)}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)

from sklearn import preprocessing

df_list = [df1,df2]

def loop_scaler(df_list):
    scaled_df_list = []
    for df in df_list:
        df_array = df.values
        min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
        df_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(df_array)
        df_scaled = pd.DataFrame(df_scaled, columns = df.columns)
        scaled_df_list.append(df_scaled)
    return scaled_df_list
```

You can print and look at the scaled output:

```
scaled_df_list = loop_scaler(df_list)
for scaled_df in scaled_df_list:
    print(scaled_df.head(5))
```

or

```
scaled_df1, scaled_df2 = loop_scaler(df_list)
print(scaled_df1.show())
print(scaled_df2.show())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
data = [[-1, 2], [-0.5, 6], [0, 10], [1, 18]]
new_data = pd.DataFrame(data)
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
transformed_data = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(new_data))
```

This may help to solve your problem.